# LVDS pairs close to other pairs

Tags: lvds

Is it a problem when I keep different LVDS traces really close to each other[image]?

Comment: What does *close* mean to you? More than five times the thickness of the prepreg? No problem then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a TI app note:

> The distance between two adjacent LVDS pairs should be greater than or equal to twice the distance between the two individual conductors of a single LVDS pair.

ref: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snla302&ved=2ahUKEwjx9omttvPsAhXwmHIEHQbKBrEQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2dkU0Z-NQgdMpnHU7sOfLr

Comment: Some people could be tempted to move the conductors of a pair closer to each other.

Comment: Our default routing guidelines are 25 mil separation between differential pairs, and 15 mil separation between conductors of a diff pair.  So not quite the 2X of the TI recommendation.

Comment: @SteveSh - if you want to ensure that the characteristic impedance of the differential pair matches the termination then the spacing will depend upon trace width and proximity of ground plane (prepress thickness if there is a ground plane on the adjacent layer). I normally use 3x clearance.

Comment: @Kevin White - Agreed,  But the question was about closeness of LVDS diif pairs to one another.